# Get React.refs DOM node width after render and trigger a re-render only if width has value has changed

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm attempting to get the width of a `ref` DOM element and set `state` to then use within the Component `render`. The problem comes because this width changes on user input and when I try `setState` within `componentDidUpdate` it starts an infinite loop and my browsers bombs.

I created a fiddle here http://jsbin.com/dizomohaso/1/edit?js,output (open the console for some information)

My thinking was;

- Component Mounts, `setState: refs.element.clientWidth`
- User inputs data, triggers `render`
- `shouldComponentUpdate` returns `true` only if `new.state` is **not** equal to `old.state`. My problem is, I'm not sure where makes sense to update this `state`?

Any help will be much appreciated, thanks for reading!

Brad.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
var component = React.createClass({

  componentDidMount: function() {

    //Get initial width. Obviously, this will trigger a render,
    //but nothing will change, look wise.
    //But, if this is against personal taste then store this property 
    //in a different way
    //But it'll complicate your determineWidth logic a bit.        

    this.setState({
      elWidth: ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.the_input).getBoundingClientRect().width
    })
  },

  determineWidth: function() {

    var elWidth = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.the_input).getBoundingClientRect().width

    if (this.state.elWidth && this.state.elWidth !== elWidth) {

      this.setState({
        elWidth: elWidth
      })

    }

  },

  render: function() {

    var styleProp = {}

    if (this.state.elWidth) {
      styleProp.style = { width: this.state.elWidth };
    }

    return (
      <input ref="the_input" onChange={this.determineWidth} {...styleProp} />
    )

  }

})
```

I like to use `.getBoundingClientRect().width` because depending on your browser, the element might have a fractional width, and that width will return without any rounding.

Comment: I am trying to use the above method but my linter is saying I should not use `findDOMNode` according to [this rule](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/no-find-dom-node.md). I tried to use `this.refs.node.getBoundingClientRect().width` but it is giving an error. Is there any alternative to find `width`, without using `findDOMNode `.

Comment: I'm assuming you defined the `node` ref. It probably isn't an HTML Element, but a container, or react component. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect

Get the HTML element you need and get its width.

Comment: You are damn right. It was a react element; `getBoundingClientRect ` working perfectly fine with HTML element. Thank you.